# Set column-count from attribute in CSS3

Tags: html, css, client-side

I've tried to read the number of columns from HTML attribute.
Something like this one:

```css
div.columns[cols] {
    column-count: attr(cols)
    -webkit-column-count: attr(cols) /* Chrome, Opera, Safari */
    -moz-column-count: attr(cols) /* Firefox */
}
```

It doesn't seem to work, and I don't know if I'm missing something or it just won't work. And if so, it would be nice to have a better solution than this:

```css
div.columns[cols="2"] {
    column-count: 2
    -webkit-column-count: 2 /* Chrome, Opera, Safari */
    -moz-column-count: 2 /* Firefox */
}
div.columns[cols="3"] {
    column-count: 3
    -webkit-column-count: 3 /* Chrome, Opera, Safari */
    -moz-column-count: 3 /* Firefox */
}
div.columns[cols="4"] {
    column-count: 4
    -webkit-column-count: 4 /* Chrome, Opera, Safari */
    -moz-column-count: 4 /* Firefox */
}
div.columns[cols="5"] {
    column-count: 5
    -webkit-column-count: 5 /* Chrome, Opera, Safari */
    -moz-column-count: 5 /* Firefox */
}
```

Thank you ;)

Comment: As Paulie_D mentioned, I don't think you can use `attr()` here. At most you could avoid writing multiple lines of code using some preprocessor but the compiled CSS would still be as lengthy as the one in your question.

Comment: Thank you guys. I thought so. Maybe there's still too much to be done for css4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't do that.

The permitted options per [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-count) are:

> column-count: integer /* an actual number */
>
> column-count: auto;
>
> column-count: inherit;
>
> column-count: initial;
>
> column-count: unset;

Comment: I saw your comment, and as I said: thank you. I thought it was this way. But those are the more-like-suggested options not really an standard, is it? And that's why the css names have -moz- and -webkit- prefixes. Anyway, I think an implementation like the first one should be nice for future updates. Well, thanks for yor answer.

Answer (score -2):

You can actually do it just look at the grammar http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#attr-notation although I've not tried it so I have no idea what the browser support is like.

You would need to use the data- prefix on the html attribute eg:

```
<div class="columns" data-cols="n">content</div>
```

And make sure you pass the second argument to attr so your css would look like this:

```
div.columns {
column-count: attr(cols integer)
-webkit-column-count: attr(cols integer)
-moz-column-count: attr(cols integer)
}
```

Comment: I'm not giving you a -1 but try to test it first. I haven't tried all the browser but it's not working for me. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: This solution doesn't work. Providing either `number` or `integer` doesn't make a difference